# Reference for Weyl Character Formula

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am reading Lie algebra book by James E.Humphreys. This book giving enough discussion about Weyl Character Formula and its proof, still I would like to know what are the other books or lecture notes where I can find the proof of this formula as well its application in various semi simple Lie algebras.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I liked very much the approach to the Lie theory of  [Anthony Knapp - Lie Groups Beyond an Introduction](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Lie_Groups_Beyond_an_Introduction.html?id=U573NrppkA8C). Here the author develop the same theory of the Humphreys and use it in the Representations of Lie Algebras and of Lie Groups, emphasizing on the connection between them.

If you like combinatorics, you can be interesten to the theory of Representation developed in [Fulton, Harris - Representation Theory](http://books.google.it/books/about/Representation_Theory.html?id=6GUH8ARxhp8C&redir_esc=y). There are a lot of chapters about the Representations of Lie Algebras, one of them about the Weyl Characters formula and its connection with Determinants and Schur Polynomials

Another interesting book could be [V.S.Varadarajan - Lie Groups, Lie Algebras and Their Representation](http://books.google.it/books/about/Lie_Groups_Lie_Algebras_and_Their_Repres.html?id=3tGugV-HhtkC&redir_esc=y) for this Theory viewed by an analytic approach.